# Bounds on integral and functions

Tags: real-analysis

(Homework) I need to show that for all $a > \frac{1}{2}$:
\begin{align*} (\int_0^{1-s} ((x + s)^a - x^a)^2 dx)^{\frac{1}{2}} \leq C s
\end{align*}
for all $0 < s \leq 1$ for some sufficiently large C.

Some ideas on bounds that I could use would be really helpful.

I tried to integrate $((x + s)^a - x^a)^2 = (x+s)^{2a} -2 (x+s)^a x^a + x^{2a}$ but I couldn't find the right bounds.

Also I need to show that no such C exists for all $a \leq \frac{1}{2}$.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hint for $a > \frac{1}{2}$: Find a convenient upper bound for $(x+s)^a - x^a$.

Comment: @DanielFischer I recall that $|x + y|^a \leq |x|^a + |y|^a$ for all $x,y$ and $0 < a < 1$, so $(x+s)^a - x^a \leq s^a$ for $0 < a < 1$ but now it seems to me like the bound in the exercise holds for all $0 < a < 1$.

Comment: No that last part is not true but it also doesn't help me in proving the claim.

Comment: That bound only gives you $\leqslant C\cdot s^a$, which is not enough. Think mean value theorem.

Comment: @DanielFischer Got it, many thanks. I will work on $a \leq \frac{1}{2}$ now.

Comment: Great. I haven't done it, but you may have success with a lower bound for the difference with the mean value theorem.